# How to convert a YCbCr(YUV) 4:4:4 image to 4:2:2 in java?

Tags: java, image, rgb, yuv

I can convert a rgb image to a YCbCr image, but i have no clue how to put it in 4:2:2

The objective is to create a lossy compreession program

any help?

Answer (score 0):

you could try this way , but this is how you can solve it using ffmpeg

ffmpeg -i in.avi -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -o out.yuv